# How can I make permission admin on menu sidebar php

Tags: php

How Can I make permission on menu

admin

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    TESTNAME      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

permission

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         id .        |      admin_id    |      status      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |          1       |       member     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |          1       |    container     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

in my html I want to check If status = member then show menu

```
 if($status == member){
    <li>
        <a href="member.php">
          <span class="sidebar-mini">O</span>
          <span class="sidebar-normal">member</span>
        </a>
      </li>
   } else {

   }
```

Comment: I'd recommend to start [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> here is the simple demonstration.how to set permission for particular url or menu
> ```

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['your session variable'])) {
    $qry=mysqli_query($con,"select * from permission where admin_id='" . $_SESSION['your session id'] . "'");
    $data=mysqli_fetch_array($qry);
    $status= $data['status'];
  if($status == member){ ?>
    <li>
        <a href="member.php">
          <span class="sidebar-mini">O</span>
          <span class="sidebar-normal">member</span>
        </a>
      </li>
  <?php } else {

   }

}
```

Comment: where is $status= $data['status']; come from ?

Comment: from your permission table

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that while you authorize(login) your user by simple JOIN statement:

```
SELECT admin.id, admin.name, permissions.status FROM admin INNER JOIN permissions ON permissions.admin_id = admin.id WHERE admin.name = '" . $user_name . "'
```

Where *$user_name* is a string representation of the *name* from your admin table, in case you retrieve your users by this value. You can change that to:

```
... admin.id = (int)$user_id
```

If for some reason you already know the ID. Of course it's always way better to use some SQL Driver or at least the PHP SQLi Driver and **prepare** the arguments provided in a query: [mysqli.prepare](http://php.net/manual/bg/mysqli.prepare.php). You should **ALWAYS** escape variables provided in a query according to expected type and it is even more important to **ALWAYS**, **ALWAYS** do that when they are provided by an external user.

So if you execute that query, then at your template you can have *$data['status']* as well as *$data['name']*.

I would also recommend changing this condition:

```
if($status == member){
```

Into:

```
if('member' === $status) {
```

It's recommended to have the string on the left, that way you can't mix up your variable, next *member* is a string and typed without quotes could sometimes be wrongly interpreted as a constant.
I would also encourage not using Queries inside your templates, better separate your logic and also check about using Template engines like Twig, Smarty, etc. which would give you the ability to separate your logic even more and stop using php code directly in your Views.

Best of luck :).

Comment: oh thank you a lot = ]